# Regular expression question in Visual Studio code

Tags: regex, visual-studio

In visual studio code, I want to be able to replace the comma followed by newline and opening brace with just the opening brace. I cannot simply replace the comma as there are commas elsewhere in the file.

What I tried in the Find bar with Regular expression mode on:

Find : `,$\n^{`

Replace : `\n{`

But its unable to match using the expression. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select `.*` to support regex.

[image]

I've tried your test case and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
},\r?\n{
```

and replace with `}{`.

[image]

`\r?\n` matches CRLF or LF line endings. There is no need to add extra anchors, they are implicit on both sides of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

In your ***Visual Code*** use replace dialog (keys Ctrl+H) and regular expression (keys Alt+R).

In first edit box use this regular expression:

```
\s*[&,]\n
```

In the second edit box use nothing (or space)
Use replace all (Ctrl+Alt+Enter )

I used this input:

```
},
{}
```

this is the result:

```
}{}
```